# Is it possible to pick images of a person face in iOS, much like the photo gallery does?

Tags: ios

The project needs to select a photo of a person, so the requirement is to group images of the photopicker by people. 
I don't seem to find any clue about this kind of functionality online... 
Is it even open for development?
Thanks

Comment: Use the PhotoKit framework. Access asset collection with the desired type/subtype.

Comment: use `PhotoKit`  or else use `CIDetector` type `CIDetectorTypeFace` for e.g : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/cidetectortypeface-how-to-detect-faces-in-a-uiimage

Comment: so what it will do if a picture contains multiple persons? @rmaddy

Comment: Multiple persons are allowed, providing the person is included

Comment: i understand but what if i want to create one folder for each person photo in gallary i mean if there are pictures of 10 person in my phone then there will be 10 folder, in a case one single picture contains all 10 person in single photo, in which folder this picture will be added ? @ted